# Print stacktrace using Frida

Tags: frida

I'm able to sucessfully hook into an Android method using Frida, but I am trying to find out who is calling that method. I can find that out if I can rewrite the method with Frida to print the stacktrace when the method gets called. I've tried a few things, but all of them have had some sort of error. This is the latest thing I have tried.

```
setImmediate(function() {
    console.log("[*] Starting script");
    Java.perform(function () {
      var Activity = Java.use("com.package.MyClass");
      Activity.getUpdates.overload('boolean', 'java.lang.String', 'java.lang.String').implementation  = function (v1, v2, v3) {
        console.log("v1: " + v1);
        console.log("v2: " + v2);
        console.log("v3: " + v3);
        Java.use("android.util.Log").getStackTraceString(Java.use("java.lang.Exception").$new())
      };
    });
})
```

This is resulting in the following error

```
Error: Not allowed outside Java.perform() callback
    at d (frida/node_modules/frida-java/index.js:86)
    at frida/node_modules/frida-java/index.js:366
    at [anon] (repl1.js:11)
    at input:1
```

Any idea how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I fixed it by using this:

```
Java.perform(function() {
    console.log(Java.use("android.util.Log").getStackTraceString(Java.use("java.lang.Exception").$new()))
});
```

It is necessary to add an additional `Java.perform` call

Comment: Have you used Frida with Python bindings?

Comment: Yes, I'm new to Frida, is there a difference? Do you need additional code? I used it with Frida server and Frida gadget

Comment: there is another issue which I've been stuck for 2 weeks or so, I thought maybe you know how to deal with it. Have you used reactor while using Frida with Python?

Comment: no, sorry I haven't used reactor yet. Maybe open a new question here

Comment: I have posted a new question about a new problem. Can you please take a look at it too? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48772800/print-class-data-member-with-frida