# Frida Android: Hook StringBuilder and print data only from a specific class

Tags: security, hook, reverse-engineering, code-injection, frida

I have hooked the StringBuilder class method toString by using this code

```
Java.perform(function() {
  const StringBuilder = Java.use('java.lang.StringBuilder');
  StringBuilder.toString.implementation = function() {

    var res = this.toString();
    var tmp = "";
    if (res !== null) {
      tmp = res.toString().replace("/n", "");
      console.log(tmp);
    }

    return res;
  };

});
```

This code is printing a ton of irrelevant data. I just want to print the data from a specific class/method. How it can be accomplished? 
Thanks

Comment: You could get the stack trace and check which method/class is the caller: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48480980/print-stacktrace-using-frida

Comment: I have tried that but process is getting terminated because of a lot of exceptions. I have checked the logs, its saying "JNI ERROR (app bug): local reference table overflow (max=512)"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have not tested the code but the following should work:

Also hook the specific method that uses StringBuilder.toString() you are interested in and set a variable that enables your StringBuilder hooking code just while you are in that method:

```
var sbActivate = false;

Java.perform(function() {
  const StringBuilder = Java.use('java.lang.StringBuilder');
  StringBuilder.toString.implementation = function() {

    var res = this.toString();
    if (sbActivate) {
        var tmp = "";
        if (res !== null) {
          tmp = res.toString().replace("/n", "");
          console.log(tmp);
        }
    }
    return res;
  };

});

Java.perform(function() {
  const someclass = Java.use('<the specific class you are interested in>');
  someclass.someMethod.implementation = function() {

    sbActivate = true;
    var res = this.someMethod();
    sbActivate = false;

    return res;
  };

});
```